# Rails 3: Retrieve content separately for each Association through AJAX 

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-javascript

My system has the following associations set up:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many : suggestions
has_many : comments
has_many : references
```

On the *Show* view of my Book model, I want to give user an option to choose (from a drop box) the view they would like to see. So for example if a user selects *suggestions* from this drop box then the partial reloads with the suggestions. Similarly for the other 3 options. 
In order to achieve this, I wrote the following method in my Model, *book.rb*:

```
def self.select_content_type(content_type)
case content_type

when "suggestions"
  # get the suggestions
  @book_suggestions = Book.suggestions.paginate(:per_page => 6, :page => params[:page])
  # return this
  return @book_suggestions

when "comments"
  # get the comments
  @book_comments = Book.comments.paginate(:per_page => 6, :page => params[:page])
  # return this
  return @book_comments

when "references"
  # get the references
  @book_references = Book.references.paginate(:per_page => 6, :page => params[:page])
  # return this
  return @book_references
```

end

end

I am trying to access this method in the "Show" action of my book_controller.rb as follows:

```
@book_content = Book.select_content_type(params[:content_type])
```

In the *Show* view, I have the following form to make a get request to this method:

```
   - form_tag  book_path(@book), :id=>"select_rel_form", :remote => true, :method => 'get' do               
      = text_field_tag :content_type, params[:content_type], :id=>"select_rel_type"
      = submit_tag "submit", :name => nil, :class=>"select_rel_submit"
```

And in a partial named *_content* I am accessing the value returned as follows:

```
- if !@book_content.nil?
  - @issue_relations.each do |relation|
    ...
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `suggestions' for #<Class:0x1177f4b8>):
app/models/book.rb:93:in `select_content_type'
app/controllers/books_controller.rb:21:in `show'
```

Kindly help me understand how I can fix this. If there's a correct and better way to achieve this, please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: You book.rb method self.select_content_type will never work. You're referencing params[:page] in the model, but you don't have that variable. params is in the controller, and I don't see where you pass it into the model.

Comment: @redronin, I am using will_paginate to paginate the content (display 6 at a time). params[:page] is a will_paginate parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form tag has select_content_type and as it says it's undefined, but there you should have something like book_path(@book)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now the form seems to access the Model method as required. However I am getting another error (updated the question). Somehow, the .suggestions association is not being recognized correctly.

Comment: Its not recognized because you have `Book.comments` where you should have something like `@book = Book.find(params[:id])` and then `@book_comments = @book.comments.paginate(:per_page => 6, :page => params[:page])`

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but your self.select_content_type method could be much DRYer:

```
def self.select_content_type(content_type)
  return unless ['suggestions', 'comments', 'references'].include?(content_type)
  Book.send(content_type.to_sym).paginate(:per_page => 6, :page => params[:page])
end
```

Also, you use params[:page] but you never pass in params. You should just leave this method in the controller, not sure why it needs to be in the model.

Comment: @redorin, do you suggest that I make it a controller method and specify routes in my *routes.rb* file? Could you please guide me why that'll be a better thing in this case?